# Are there any abnormal vote activities in this question?

Tags: discussion, upvotes

I was browsing questions that generated reversal badge and found a question which has a surprising high score currently (timeline given):

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21929223/timeline

and a more surprised thing is, the question starts receiving upvotes continually after a bundle of downvotes at beginning, and didn't get any downvotes again, so I suspect if there is any unusual upvotes there (I'm not sure if it is normal, so I don't flag it).

Comment: @Tushar Vote are always anonymous this is why they're marked N/A

Comment: @yellowantphil: until we delete it. It's not as if that same web search will *not* turn up an official reference for `tar` as well.

Comment: Looks pretty normal, it is currently the top hit at Google when you query "tar zxvf".  That's how old posts get views and votes.  Google doesn't otherwise care or note that a question is closed or off topic.

Comment: @RadLexus: Does everything that gets linked from meta need to be deteled? It was a clear question, with a concise answer. Voted to undelete.

Comment: @user000001 It's 100% offtopic, shouldn't have been answered (especially not by a high-rep user who should know better) and should have been deleted ~3 years ago when it was closed.

Comment: @user000001 And if you're worried that we deleted valuable information, [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61461/how-to-extract-specific-files-from-tar-gz) is a similar question on Unix & Linux SE, and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/567363/what-are-the-different-arguments-passed-to-tar-command) is the same question on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @Stijn: So it's answered somewhere else as well. That's no reason to delete it IMO. My comment wasn't targeted to this specific question so much though, but mostly to the tendency of some meta users to delete everything they see, just because it happens to be closed.

Comment: @user000001: when we get pointed to a question, we take a look. [Nothing surprising about that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect). Most complaints on the Meta-Effect are due to downvotes and closevotes, and not that much about upvotes, reopening, and undeleting questions – even though we also do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see nothing wrong for voting on this question.

Initial downvotes indicate that author done zero research (and possibly that post is off-topic).

Over time it got 18 upvotes in couple years which indicates that question is useful for multiple people and never was featured on any specific site like redit.

Note that votes always reported as "by = N/A", so that is not an indication of a problem by itself.