# What is the rationale for requiring more votes to undelete "good" questions/answers than "bad" ones?

Tags: discussion, voting, vote-to-undelete

The number of delete votes that are required to delete a question by high-rep users, depends on the score of the question and its answers. From the help center:

> It takes 3 votes, minimum, to delete a closed question. However, the number of delete votes required scales to the number of votes on the question and all its answers.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions

This makes perfect sense, since we generally don't want good content to be deleted.

However, this rule seems to apply for un-deletions too! For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21929223/what-does-zxvf-mean-in-tar-zxvf-filename) has already received three undelete votes, but hasn't been undeleted, due to the high score of the question and its answers.

So the "better" a Q/A is judged by the community, the harder it is for the Q/A to be undeleted. If the above question had been downvoted, it would currently be undeleted based on the undelete votes it has received.

I believe that it should be *easier* to undelete "good" Q/As, than "bad" ones. Therefore I am requesting for the current system to change regarding the undelete votes requirements. My proposal would be to have a starting value of 3 undelete votes maximun, with **fewer** undelete votes required when the score of the question and the answers is high.

So the question is this: What is the rationale for requiring more votes to undelete "good" questions/answers than "bad" ones? Wouldn't it make more sense for "good" content to be easier to salvage that "bad" content.

Note that I don't believe that there is a perfect correlation between post quality and score, but this is the metric the system currently uses, and I don't think that anybody has proposed a better metric.

Comment: This is an excellent example of why the current system works perfectly. The question you mention has nothing to do on SO and should not be undeleted. It is a good thing that a mere three votes do not suffice.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: So if it was downvoted it would make more sense to undelete it?

Comment: I fail to understand your comment. The problem is that the question has accumulated a lot of upvoted answers (probably from searches) despite its very poor quality. Therefore, more delete votes were necessary to get rid of it. We absolutely do not want this effort to be wasted by allowing only three, possibly even less, misguided users to undelete it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: But three votes would be enough if the question was *actually* a bad one. But because the community judged it to be a good one, it is harder to undo the damage caused by the [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338029/are-there-any-abnormal-vote-activities-in-this-question) on that question.

Comment: The question *is* actually a bad one. Or do we disagree here?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Yes we do. The question was a top search result to `tar zxvf`

Comment: That's the crux of the problem then. Just because some question is a top search result does not necessarily mean it is good. In fact, in my personal experience, the opposite is often true. It is a good thing the system prevented you from undeleting it, IMHO.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Well we should agree to disagree. I really don't see how deleting it makes the internet a better place. If anything it makes it harder to find the answer. Some people believe that it is not 100% programming related, so they closed it, which I am fine with, but I fail to see any advantages in keeping it deleted.

Comment: But the point of this question still remains regardless of what someone believes about the specific question. Good content should be easier to undelete than bad content. That's all I am saying.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would have a better reception using an example with is not heading for an answer copying TFM and absolutely off topic on stack overflow. But I've the feeling you won't find one easily.

Comment: The question being deleted means that not everyone agrees with you calling it "good content". Upvotes do not mean a post is good.

Comment: amount of upvotes doesn't reliably indicate good questions, this is explained in  [The Trouble With Popularity](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/) article: "we discovered that these posts... truly start to drown out everything else on the site... it's too addictive and too easy, and in the absence of any moderation, the community would do nothing but add and upvote the easy, fun stuff. This is why community moderators have real power; they _need_ that power to intervene, educate, and refocus the community's exuberance on more substantive content..."

Comment: The question getting deleted sounds like a great cure to it being a top search result.

Comment: @Pekka웃: Not sure if your comment is serious or not... Would you be unhappy to find it as a search result if you had the same question? I find the deleted answer really direct and to the point, with no distracting information...

Comment: @user a deleted answer will send a 404 status to Google and should be de-indexed pretty quickly. I agree it sucks that potentially good content is lost but if you don't guard on-topicness rules on a site with > 12m questions, the result is a disaster. Deletion really is the only way to prevent closed questions (whose quality typically deteriorates over time for lack of updates and nee answers) from polluting  search results.

Comment: Side note: earlier set of comments on linked questions available at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338029/are-there-any-abnormal-vote-activities-in-this-question

Answer (score 17):

If *that many* users voted to delete a question that *used to be* considered good, it should take *just as many* users to overrule that decision.

These old upvoted questions are often no longer relevant / on-topic on Stack Overflow. The fact that a question with that many upvotes *did* get deleted, indicates that it really isn't considered "good", any more.

I agree with:

> *Good content should be easier to undelete than bad content.*

But the linked question doesn't fall under the category *"Good content"*.

Comment: I dissagre that the number of votes for deleting and undeleting should be equal. When a question is deleted it gets *significantly* fewer views than before, so it is really hard to get any undelete votes.

Comment: _"so it is really hard to get any undelete votes"_ - Why is this a problem?

Comment: @user000001 It's actually as hard as deleting it in the first place. Very few visitors from Google have the privilege to delete. There's only [the moderator tools](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last14days), that are showing active questions with delete and undelete votes, but that tool is really unusable.

Comment: @Cerbrus: It is a problem for the people looking for the information, as well as for the people that believe that the deletion wasn't warranted.

Comment: @Tunaki: I agree that it is unusable. And also that the origin of the visits is correlated to the moderation abilities of the users. My experience with deletions has been that it is very rare for anything to get undeleted. On the contrary deletions are very likely, especially for closed questions linked from meta.

Comment: @user000001: I'm looking for the best method to cook my rib-eye on here, but that doesn't mean questions answering that should be undeleted. Why should a undelete-vote weigh heavier? Why should a person's vote have more influence if he disagrees with the deletion, than when he wants to get something deleted?

Comment: @user, the information is still accessible. The deleted SO question is only the third hit on my Google search. The first hit is [this](http://www.tecmint.com/18-tar-command-examples-in-linux/), which contains the relevant information.